Hibernate: Update OneToOne id
Use case: All programmers are persons, but all persons are not programmers. Persons are created first, and at a later stage the decision gets made to add the programmer attributes. The relationship between programmer and person is always 1:1.
Question: How do I specify the personId when creating a programmer record? The FE only passes the personId, and I do not want to get the entire Person object first.
If I declare the personId as part of the Programmer class, I get the error "Column 'person_id' is duplicated in mapping for entity"
I only need the Person as part of the Programmer when I select records from the DB, I do not need it for inserts or updates.
If I remove the personId declaration, I no longer have access to it in my builder class or any getters and setters:
This will give a "cannot find symbol - symbol: method getPersonId()" error:
        Programmer programmer = programmerRepository.save(Programmer.builder()
                .personId(programmerDto.getPersonId())
                .organizationId(programmerDto.getOrganizationId())
                .build());

@Data
@Entity
@Builder
...
public class Programmer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    long programmerId;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text", length = 50, nullable = false)
    String programingLanguage;

//    @Column(nullable = false)
//    long personId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    @JoinColumn(name = "personId")
    private Person person;
}

@Data
@Entity
...
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "person_generator")
    long personId;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text", length = 10)
    String name;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text", length = 100)
    String surname;
}



If you only need person when fetching a developer under certain situations, don't use @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN) and instead make it lazy fetched. You can then control when it is fetched so that it only happens when needed. Then you can take in partial developer instances that may not have a person associated and merge the changes into a Developer instance read from JPA yourself, allowing you to ignore the null person reference so it remains unchanged. Otherwise, if you want to control the FK via the long person ID, you have to make one of the mappings to the fk read only

Your approach is against the OOP concept.
You might want to do something like this. I have not tested this but it might help you to find the right solution
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Programmer")
@Builder
...
public class Programmer extends Person {

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text", length = 50, nullable = false)
    String programingLanguage;
}

@Data
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "Person")
...
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "person_generator")
    long personId;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text", length = 10)
    String name;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text", length = 100)
    String surname;
}

Or you can try something like this
https://igorski.co/entity-inheritance-jpa-hibernate/
